# Calling out positional argument

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, positional-argument

I have a python 2.5 function with a definition like:

```
def Foo(a, b='Silly', c='Walks', d='Spam', e='Eggs', f='Ni', *addl):
```

Where `addl` can be any number of strings (filenames) to do something with.

I'm fine with all of the defaults, but I have filenames to put in `addl`.

I am inclined to do something like:

```
Foo('me@domain.com', addl=('File1.txt', 'File2.txt'))
```

But that gets the following error:

```
TypeError: Foo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'addl'
```

**Is there a syntax where I can succinctly call** `Foo` **with just the first required parameter and my (variable number of) additional strings?** Or am I stuck redundantly specifying all of the defaults before I can break into the `addl` argument range?

For the sake of argument, the function definition is not able to be modified or refactored.

Comment: Just unpack tuple, it should work: Foo('me@domain.com', *('File1.txt', 'File2.txt'))

Comment: @AndreyT: That doesn't work.  It assigns `'File1.txt'` to `a`, and `'File2.txt'` to `b`.

Comment: Yep, you right. So, in case of 2.5 possible solution is usage kwargs instead of b,c,d,e,f parameters.

Comment: @AndreyT It is not specific to `Python 2.5`, right? Can we say that it hold true for `Python>2.5`? I tried this on `Python 2.7` and assigns `File2.txt` to `b` as well.

Comment: @AndreyT: The problem with that would be the unmitigated affect on all the other code using `Foo`

Comment: @malhar: It's bit specific to 2.x. In 3.x we can use folow definition: def f(a, *args, b=1, c=2, etc=3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if function can't be modified, then why not create wrapper?

```
def foo_with_defaults(a, *addl):
    Foo(a, *(Foo.func_defaults + addl))

foo_with_defaults('me@domain.com', *('File1.txt', 'File2.txt'))
```

Comment: "For the sake of argument, the function definition is not able to be modified or refactored."

Comment: `Foo.func_defaults` was the key piece I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it is not possible.

First you need to pass required (a) and default (b, c, d, e, f) arguments, and then every additional argument is passed as *addl:

```
Foo('me@domain.com', 'Silly', 'Walks', 'Spam', 'Eggs', 'Ni', 'File1.txt', 'File2.txt')
```

Comment: So your answer to "is there a syntax where I can succinctly call Foo with just the first required parameter and my (variable number of) additional strings?" is "no"? Are you certain this is the one and only approach?

Comment: Sorry for not answering the question precisely. To my knowledge it is not possible. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `addl` as a keyword argument, but you defined it as a positional argument. You should add one more `*` if you want to call the function like `Foo(addl=('File1.txt', 'File2.txt'))`:

```py
def Foo(a, b='Silly', c='Walks', d='Spam', e='Eggs', f='Ni', **addl):
```